# how to disable HTTP trace method in Jboss Application Server 5

Tags: jboss

How to disable HTTP TRACE Method in jboss server 5?
I tried this soln 
D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml

but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

There are the following ways to limit HTTP methods in a web application:

1. Adding security constraints in web.xml

   < security-constraint>
       < web-resource-collection>
           < web-resource-name>NoAccess
           < url-pattern>/*
             < http-method>DELETE
             < http-method>TRACE
             < http-method>OPTIONS
       
       < auth-constraint/>

   Here DELETE, TRACE and OPTIONS are restricted for all urls. curl -kvv -X DELETE < url> will give 403 Forbidden
2. Using Rewrite rules in domain.xml

   < subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
       < connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
       < virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
           < rewrite pattern=".*" substitution="-" flags="F">
               < condition test="%{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^(DELETE|TRACE|OPTIONS)$" flags="NC" />
3. Using mod_rewrite in httpd

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(DELETE|TRACE|OPTIONS)$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F]

Comment: please explain the 3rd method, RewiteEngine is not recognize in windows command prompt!!!

Comment: Third option is suggesting using mod_rewrite of Apache

Comment: can you please add the well formatted script. It seems not working with this configuration